# PyDev attach to process fails with `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'add_code_to_python_process'`

Tags: python, debugging, pydev

I am trying to use PyDev to attach to a process on MS-Windows 10. Actually, to be more precise I was doing this. It worked wonderfully and I value it immensely, but now doesn't work and I wonder why.

I always do this to the same process, it is one written in C++ that loads a python interpreter internally to run Python plugin code. I have in past been happily breaking inside the plugin code and debugging with PyDev.

Come Dec 2020 and I try again and I get this error when trying to attach to the same process:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Util\Eclipse\dropins\PyDev 8.1.0\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_8.1.0.202012051215\pysrc\pydevd_attach_to_process\attach_pydevd.py", line 72, in <module>
    main(process_command_line(sys.argv[1:]))
  File "E:\Util\Eclipse\dropins\PyDev 8.1.0\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_8.1.0.202012051215\pysrc\pydevd_attach_to_process\attach_pydevd.py", line 41, in main
    import add_code_to_python_process
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'add_code_to_python_process'
Process finished with exitValue: 1
```

I last did this successfully around Oct 2020. I don't need this much. But when I do, it's ver very useful.

The error message isn't very helpful to me. I have searched on-line and through all my prior notes and found no clues.

Crucial of course in any "Was working, but isn't now" scenario is "what's changed". Well a good few things, not least the application I ma debugging is under constant development and I am regularly fetching new builds and running them. Also I have likely upgraded Eclipse and definitely upgraded PyDev since.

In fact suspecting some odd PyDev corruption I removed it and installed the latest one fresh using the Eclipse dropins method, which I have always used here and has worked fine.

The message suggests that this is failing on the Eclipse/PyDev side not the target process. Specifically that:

```
E:\Util\Eclipse\dropins\PyDev 8.1.0\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_8.1.0.202012051215\pysrc\pydevd_attach_to_process\attach_pydevd.py
```

tries on line 41 to `import add_code_to_python_process` and cant find the module, and that is an entirely PyDev internal issue it seems.

But checking the PyDev install:

```
E:\> tree "E:\Util\Eclipse\dropins\PyDev 8.1.0\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_8.1.0.202012051215\pysrc" /f
Folder PATH listing for volume DATA
Volume serial number is 646C-4A23
E:\UTIL\ECLIPSE\DROPINS\PYDEV 8.1.0\PLUGINS\ORG.PYTHON.PYDEV.CORE_8.1.0.202012051215\PYSRC
│   conftest.py
│   interpreterInfo.py
│   LICENSE
│   MANIFEST.in
│   pycompletionserver.py
│   pydevconsole.py
│   pydevd.py
│   pydevd_file_utils.py
│   pydevd_tracing.py
│   pydev_app_engine_debug_startup.py
│   pydev_coverage.py
│   pydev_pysrc.py
│   pydev_run_in_console.py
│   pytest.ini
│   README.rst
│   runfiles.py
│   setup.py
│   setup_cython.py
│
├───.github
│   │   install_and_run_debug_py.sh
│   │
│   └───workflows
│           pydevd-tests-python.yml
│
├───build_tools
│       build.py
│       build_binaries_osx.py
│       build_binaries_windows.py
│       check_no_git_modifications.py
│       generate_code.py
│       names_to_rename.py
│       pydevd_release_process.txt
│       rename_pep8.py
│
├───pydevd_attach_to_process
│   │   add_code_to_python_process.py
│   │   attach_amd64.dll
│   │   attach_linux_amd64.so
│   │   attach_linux_x86.so
│   │   attach_pydevd.py
│   │   attach_script.py
│   │   attach_x86.dll
│   │   attach_x86.dylib
│   │   attach_x86_64.dylib
│   │   inject_dll_amd64.exe
│   │   inject_dll_x86.exe
│   │   README.txt
│   │   run_code_on_dllmain_amd64.dll
│   │   run_code_on_dllmain_x86.dll
│   │   _always_live_program.py
│   │   _check.py
│   │   _test_attach_to_process.py
│   │   _test_attach_to_process_linux.py
│   │
│   ├───common
│   │       python.h
│   │       py_custom_pyeval_settrace.hpp
│   │       py_settrace.hpp
│   │       py_utils.hpp
│   │       py_version.hpp
│   │       ref_utils.hpp
│   │
│   ├───linux_and_mac
│   │       attach.cpp
│   │       compile_linux.sh
│   │       compile_mac.sh
│   │       lldb_prepare.py
│   │
│   ├───winappdbg
│   │   │   breakpoint.py
│   │   │   compat.py
│   │   │   crash.py
│   │   │   debug.py
│   │   │   disasm.py
│   │   │   event.py
│   │   │   interactive.py
│   │   │   module.py
│   │   │   process.py
│   │   │   registry.py
│   │   │   search.py
│   │   │   sql.py
│   │   │   system.py
│   │   │   textio.py
│   │   │   thread.py
│   │   │   util.py
│   │   │   window.py
│   │   │   __init__.py
│   │   │
│   │   ├───plugins
│   │   │       do_example.py
│   │   │       do_exchain.py
│   │   │       do_exploitable.py
│   │   │       do_symfix.py
│   │   │       README
│   │   │       __init__.py
│   │   │
│   │   └───win32
│   │           advapi32.py
│   │           context_amd64.py
│   │           context_i386.py
│   │           dbghelp.py
│   │           defines.py
│   │           gdi32.py
│   │           kernel32.py
│   │           ntdll.py
│   │           peb_teb.py
│   │           psapi.py
│   │           shell32.py
│   │           shlwapi.py
│   │           user32.py
│   │           version.py
│   │           wtsapi32.py
│   │           __init__.py
│   │
│   └───windows
│           attach.cpp
│           attach.h
│           compile_windows.bat
│           inject_dll.cpp
│           py_win_helpers.hpp
│           run_code_in_memory.hpp
│           run_code_on_dllmain.cpp
│           stdafx.cpp
│           stdafx.h
│           targetver.h
│
├───pydevd_concurrency_analyser
│       pydevd_concurrency_logger.py
│       pydevd_thread_wrappers.py
│       __init__.py
│
├───pydevd_plugins
│   │   django_debug.py
│   │   jinja2_debug.py
│   │   __init__.py
│   │
│   └───extensions
│       │   README.md
│       │   __init__.py
│       │
│       └───types
│               pydevd_helpers.py
│               pydevd_plugins_django_form_str.py
│               pydevd_plugin_numpy_types.py
│               __init__.py
│
├───pydev_ipython
│       inputhook.py
│       inputhookglut.py
│       inputhookgtk.py
│       inputhookgtk3.py
│       inputhookpyglet.py
│       inputhookqt4.py
│       inputhookqt5.py
│       inputhooktk.py
│       inputhookwx.py
│       matplotlibtools.py
│       qt.py
│       qt_for_kernel.py
│       qt_loaders.py
│       README
│       version.py
│       __init__.py
│
├───pydev_sitecustomize
│   │   sitecustomize.py
│   │   __not_in_default_pythonpath.txt
│   │
│   └───__pycache__
│           sitecustomize.cpython-38.pyc
│
├───stubs
│       pycompletion.py
│       _django_manager_body.py
│       _get_tips.py
│
├───third_party
│   │   cython_json.py
│   │   tests_cython_json.py
│   │
│   ├───isort_container
│   │   ├───backports
│   │   │       functools_lru_cache.py
│   │   │       __init__.py
│   │   │
│   │   └───isort
│   │           finders.py
│   │           hooks.py
│   │           isort.py
│   │           main.py
│   │           natural.py
│   │           pie_slice.py
│   │           pylama_isort.py
│   │           settings.py
│   │           utils.py
│   │           __init__.py
│   │           __main__.py
│   │
│   ├───pep8
│   │   │   autopep8.py
│   │   │   pycodestyle.py
│   │   │
│   │   └───lib2to3
│   │       └───lib2to3
│   │           │   btm_matcher.py
│   │           │   btm_utils.py
│   │           │   fixer_base.py
│   │           │   fixer_util.py
│   │           │   Grammar.txt
│   │           │   main.py
│   │           │   patcomp.py
│   │           │   PatternGrammar.txt
│   │           │   pygram.py
│   │           │   pytree.py
│   │           │   refactor.py
│   │           │   __init__.py
│   │           │   __main__.py
│   │           │
│   │           ├───fixes
│   │           │       fix_apply.py
│   │           │       fix_basestring.py
│   │           │       fix_buffer.py
│   │           │       fix_callable.py
│   │           │       fix_dict.py
│   │           │       fix_except.py
│   │           │       fix_exec.py
│   │           │       fix_execfile.py
│   │           │       fix_exitfunc.py
│   │           │       fix_filter.py
│   │           │       fix_funcattrs.py
│   │           │       fix_future.py
│   │           │       fix_getcwdu.py
│   │           │       fix_has_key.py
│   │           │       fix_idioms.py
│   │           │       fix_import.py
│   │           │       fix_imports.py
│   │           │       fix_imports2.py
│   │           │       fix_input.py
│   │           │       fix_intern.py
│   │           │       fix_isinstance.py
│   │           │       fix_itertools.py
│   │           │       fix_itertools_imports.py
│   │           │       fix_long.py
│   │           │       fix_map.py
│   │           │       fix_metaclass.py
│   │           │       fix_methodattrs.py
│   │           │       fix_ne.py
│   │           │       fix_next.py
│   │           │       fix_nonzero.py
│   │           │       fix_numliterals.py
│   │           │       fix_operator.py
│   │           │       fix_paren.py
│   │           │       fix_print.py
│   │           │       fix_raise.py
│   │           │       fix_raw_input.py
│   │           │       fix_reduce.py
│   │           │       fix_renames.py
│   │           │       fix_repr.py
│   │           │       fix_set_literal.py
│   │           │       fix_standarderror.py
│   │           │       fix_sys_exc.py
│   │           │       fix_throw.py
│   │           │       fix_tuple_params.py
│   │           │       fix_types.py
│   │           │       fix_unicode.py
│   │           │       fix_urllib.py
│   │           │       fix_ws_comma.py
│   │           │       fix_xrange.py
│   │           │       fix_xreadlines.py
│   │           │       fix_zip.py
│   │           │       __init__.py
│   │           │
│   │           └───pgen2
│   │                   conv.py
│   │                   driver.py
│   │                   grammar.py
│   │                   literals.py
│   │                   parse.py
│   │                   pgen.py
│   │                   token.py
│   │                   tokenize.py
│   │                   __init__.py
│   │
│   └───wrapped_for_pydev
│       │   not_in_default_pythonpath.txt
│       │
│       └───ctypes
│           │   ctypes-README.txt
│           │   util.py
│           │   wintypes.py
│           │   _ctypes.dll
│           │   _endian.py
│           │   __init__.py
│           │
│           └───macholib
│                   dyld.py
│                   dylib.py
│                   framework.py
│                   __init__.py
│
├───_pydevd_bundle
│   │   pydevconsole_code_for_ironpython.py
│   │   pydevd_additional_thread_info.py
│   │   pydevd_additional_thread_info_regular.py
│   │   pydevd_api.py
│   │   pydevd_breakpoints.py
│   │   pydevd_code_to_source.py
│   │   pydevd_collect_bytecode_info.py
│   │   pydevd_comm.py
│   │   pydevd_command_line_handling.py
│   │   pydevd_comm_constants.py
│   │   pydevd_console.py
│   │   pydevd_constants.py
│   │   pydevd_custom_frames.py
│   │   pydevd_cython.c
│   │   pydevd_cython.pxd
│   │   pydevd_cython.pyx
│   │   pydevd_cython_win32_27_32.pyd
│   │   pydevd_cython_win32_27_64.pyd
│   │   pydevd_cython_win32_36_32.cp36-win32.pyd
│   │   pydevd_cython_win32_36_64.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
│   │   pydevd_cython_win32_37_32.cp37-win32.pyd
│   │   pydevd_cython_win32_37_64.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
│   │   pydevd_cython_win32_38_32.cp38-win32.pyd
│   │   pydevd_cython_win32_38_64.cp38-win_amd64.pyd
│   │   pydevd_cython_win32_39_32.cp39-win32.pyd
│   │   pydevd_cython_win32_39_64.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
│   │   pydevd_cython_wrapper.py
│   │   pydevd_daemon_thread.py
│   │   pydevd_defaults.py
│   │   pydevd_dont_trace.py
│   │   pydevd_dont_trace_files.py
│   │   pydevd_exec.py
│   │   pydevd_exec2.py
│   │   pydevd_extension_api.py
│   │   pydevd_extension_utils.py
│   │   pydevd_filtering.py
│   │   pydevd_frame.py
│   │   pydevd_frame_utils.py
│   │   pydevd_import_class.py
│   │   pydevd_io.py
│   │   pydevd_json_debug_options.py
│   │   pydevd_net_command.py
│   │   pydevd_net_command_factory_json.py
│   │   pydevd_net_command_factory_xml.py
│   │   pydevd_plugin_utils.py
│   │   pydevd_process_net_command.py
│   │   pydevd_process_net_command_json.py
│   │   pydevd_referrers.py
│   │   pydevd_reload.py
│   │   pydevd_resolver.py
│   │   pydevd_safe_repr.py
│   │   pydevd_save_locals.py
│   │   pydevd_signature.py
│   │   pydevd_source_mapping.py
│   │   pydevd_stackless.py
│   │   pydevd_suspended_frames.py
│   │   pydevd_thread_lifecycle.py
│   │   pydevd_timeout.py
│   │   pydevd_traceproperty.py
│   │   pydevd_trace_api.py
│   │   pydevd_trace_dispatch.py
│   │   pydevd_trace_dispatch_regular.py
│   │   pydevd_utils.py
│   │   pydevd_vars.py
│   │   pydevd_vm_type.py
│   │   pydevd_xml.py
│   │   __init__.py
│   │
│   ├───_debug_adapter
│   │       debugProtocol.json
│   │       debugProtocolCustom.json
│   │       pydevd_base_schema.py
│   │       pydevd_schema.py
│   │       pydevd_schema_log.py
│   │       __init__.py
│   │       __main__pydevd_gen_debug_adapter_protocol.py
│   │
│   └───__pycache__
│           pydevd_comm_constants.cpython-38.pyc
│           pydevd_constants.cpython-38.pyc
│           pydevd_dont_trace.cpython-38.pyc
│           pydevd_frame_utils.cpython-38.pyc
│           pydevd_utils.cpython-38.pyc
│           pydevd_vm_type.cpython-38.pyc
│           __init__.cpython-38.pyc
│
├───_pydevd_frame_eval
│   │   pydevd_frame_evaluator.c
│   │   pydevd_frame_evaluator.cp38-win32.pyd
│   │   pydevd_frame_evaluator.cp38-win_amd64.pyd
│   │   pydevd_frame_evaluator.cp39-win32.pyd
│   │   pydevd_frame_evaluator.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
│   │   pydevd_frame_evaluator.pxd
│   │   pydevd_frame_evaluator.pyx
│   │   pydevd_frame_evaluator.template.pyx
│   │   pydevd_frame_evaluator_win32_36_32.cp36-win32.pyd
│   │   pydevd_frame_evaluator_win32_36_64.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
│   │   pydevd_frame_evaluator_win32_37_32.cp37-win32.pyd
│   │   pydevd_frame_evaluator_win32_37_64.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
│   │   pydevd_frame_eval_cython_wrapper.py
│   │   pydevd_frame_eval_main.py
│   │   pydevd_frame_tracing.py
│   │   pydevd_modify_bytecode.py
│   │   release_mem.h
│   │   __init__.py
│   │
│   ├───vendored
│   │   │   pydevd_fix_code.py
│   │   │   README.txt
│   │   │   __init__.py
│   │   │
│   │   └───bytecode
│   │       │   bytecode.py
│   │       │   cfg.py
│   │       │   concrete.py
│   │       │   flags.py
│   │       │   instr.py
│   │       │   peephole_opt.py
│   │       │   __init__.py
│   │       │
│   │       └───tests
│   │               test_bytecode.py
│   │               test_cfg.py
│   │               test_code.py
│   │               test_concrete.py
│   │               test_flags.py
│   │               test_instr.py
│   │               test_misc.py
│   │               test_peephole_opt.py
│   │               __init__.py
│   │
│   └───__pycache__
│           __init__.cpython-38.pyc
│
├───_pydev_bundle
│   │   pydev_console_utils.py
│   │   pydev_imports.py
│   │   pydev_import_hook.py
│   │   pydev_ipython_console.py
│   │   pydev_ipython_console_011.py
│   │   pydev_is_thread_alive.py
│   │   pydev_localhost.py
│   │   pydev_log.py
│   │   pydev_monkey.py
│   │   pydev_monkey_qt.py
│   │   pydev_override.py
│   │   pydev_umd.py
│   │   pydev_versioncheck.py
│   │   _pydev_calltip_util.py
│   │   _pydev_completer.py
│   │   _pydev_filesystem_encoding.py
│   │   _pydev_getopt.py
│   │   _pydev_imports_tipper.py
│   │   _pydev_jy_imports_tipper.py
│   │   _pydev_log.py
│   │   _pydev_tipper_common.py
│   │   __init__.py
│   │
│   └───__pycache__
│           pydev_is_thread_alive.cpython-38.pyc
│           pydev_localhost.cpython-38.pyc
│           pydev_log.cpython-38.pyc
│           _pydev_filesystem_encoding.cpython-38.pyc
│           _pydev_imports_tipper.cpython-38.pyc
│           _pydev_log.cpython-38.pyc
│           _pydev_tipper_common.cpython-38.pyc
│           __init__.cpython-38.pyc
│
├───_pydev_imps
│   │   _pydev_BaseHTTPServer.py
│   │   _pydev_execfile.py
│   │   _pydev_inspect.py
│   │   _pydev_pkgutil_old.py
│   │   _pydev_saved_modules.py
│   │   _pydev_SimpleXMLRPCServer.py
│   │   _pydev_SocketServer.py
│   │   _pydev_sys_patch.py
│   │   _pydev_xmlrpclib.py
│   │   __init__.py
│   │
│   └───__pycache__
│           _pydev_saved_modules.cpython-38.pyc
│           __init__.cpython-38.pyc
│
├───_pydev_runfiles
│       pydev_runfiles.py
│       pydev_runfiles_coverage.py
│       pydev_runfiles_nose.py
│       pydev_runfiles_parallel.py
│       pydev_runfiles_parallel_client.py
│       pydev_runfiles_pytest2.py
│       pydev_runfiles_unittest.py
│       pydev_runfiles_xml_rpc.py
│       __init__.py
│
└───__pycache__
        pydevd_file_utils.cpython-38.pyc
```

Then we can see that `add_code_to_python_process.py` is where it looks like it should be to import fine in `attach_pydevd.py` but by the by loooks like it always has.

Now I checked the target process too and the configured Python intereter, and I ensured that:

1. The very same interpreter that my target porcess is running, is used. That target process comes bundled with its own python interpreter and uses its own site-packages folder etc. All no trouble, as I simply configure that interperter under the PyDev interpreters.
2. I add the pysrcs directory tot he PYTHONPATH of that interpreter.

To illustrate (target app folder redacted out as it's not relevant):

[image: PyDev Interpreter Settings]

The nature of the error suggests a PyrDev configuration issue, that PyDev itself is not running right, but hard to see how, with a fresh install and everyhing visibly looking fine. PyDev (like any debugger) is a tad complicated, but I have read what I can and am none the wiser. It's not a bug in PyDev (or I'd file one) though, as it was working (with a prior version of PyDev I admit, as I have upgraded, but the PyDev upgrade came only as part of my effort to diagnose/fix this, in short this error ppeared first on the earlier version of PyDev I had installed with which I had on last efort (a month ago or s) connected PyDev to this same target process.

The real sticking point here is interpreting the traceback and error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really a bit odd that it doesn't find it given that it's alongside `attach_pydevd.py` and given that `attach_pydevd.py` is executed as a `__main__` module it should (in theory) be able to find it... but practice it seems is sometimes different ;)

So, try to do the following: open `attach_pydevd.py` and add `sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(__file__))` as the first line of the `def main(setup):` to see if it fixes your issue (if it does, I'll also do the fix in the debugger side).

Comment: Brilliant as ever Fabio! That worked a charm. A puzzle indeed, it worked fine a month ago. Suddenly not. A month of course introduces changes into a system, I'm working on daily, but I don't touch the Eclipse folder and I even reinstalled PyDev freshly so it was clean as can by, via the dropins folder. Very befuddling.

Comment: Great that it worked. Just fixed it in: https://github.com/fabioz/PyDev.Debugger/commit/647fca721168bcfa65ff8cdab2adae4659f3c020... I think this has more to do with the Python you're using than with the install (usually the first entry in the `sys.path` is an empty `""` to point to the initial dir, but something seems different there). Anyways, great that it's working now!